# Transitive, Directed Graph in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I am trying to make a graph transitive using SQL.

I do not see, why this should not work:

```
with recursive recursive_table(from, to) as (
    SELECT * FROM Graph
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r1.to, r2.from FROM recursive_table r1, recursive_table r2
    WHERE r1.from = r2.to
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM recursive_table
)
SELECT * FROM recursive_table;
```

In every recursion, I take the elements specified in the not transitive Graph (1), everything which is the result of the next recursion (3) and everything which results out of the next recursion (2).

However, SQL says:

```
[2021-02-12 10:36:05] [HY000][3577] In recursive query block of Recursive Common Table Expression 'recursive_table', the recursive table must be referenced only once, and not in any subquery
```

A sample output would be the following:

Input:

```
+------+------+--+
| Col1 | Col2 |  |
+------+------+--+
|    1 |    2 |  |
|    2 |    3 |  |
|    1 |    4 |  |
|    4 |    5 |  |
+------+------+--+
```

Output:

```
+------+------+--+
| Col1 | Col2 |  |
+------+------+--+
|    1 |    2 |  |
|    2 |    3 |  |
|    1 |    4 |  |
|    4 |    5 |  |
|    1 |    3 |  |
|    1 |    5 |  |
+------+------+--+
```

So, mathematically speaking,

If you can go from a to b in a finite amount of steps > 0, add (a,b) to the graph.

For example, you can go from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3 on the input data, therefore you can go from 1 to 3.

Another example is a circle with n - knots.
This means, the input would be something like this...

```
+------+------+--+
| Col1 | Col2 |  |
+------+------+--+
| 1    | 2    |  |
| 2    | 3    |  |
| 3    | ...  |  |
| ...  | n    |  |
| n    | 1    |  |
+------+------+--+
```

The correct output would be [n] X [n]

Comment: And what is not clear from the error text? Also, [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) says: *These constraints come from the SQL standard, other than the MySQL-specific exclusions of ORDER BY, LIMIT (MySQL 8.0.18 and earlier), and DISTINCT.* Please, provide sample data and desired output in text format. You can use [this tool](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to format your data in tabular view.

Comment: Also please describe the algorithm to transform your data so someone can focus on the SQL task itself without studying graph algorithms. This will make your question more likely be answered

Comment: I hope I made it clearer now  
@astentx
I have no idea what this error message is supposed to mean, and (which is more important) how to make it "correct"

Comment: Is your graph directed?

Comment: Yes. 
(-deleted--)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little hard to say exactly why your code doesn't work.  There are multiple potential issues:

- `from` is not a valid column name.
- Recursive CTEs rarely have two `union all`s.
- Recursive CTEs do not usually reference the recursive CTE multiple times.

In any case, correct code is simpler:

```
with recursive recursive_table(col1, col2) as (
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM graph
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r1.col1, g.col2
    FROM  recursive_table r1 JOIN
          graph g
          ON r1.col2 = g.col1
)
SELECT *
FROM recursive_table;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf467aedd33bc029a0697ffdce8d016b) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that both this code and your code assume that the graph has no cycles.  That is not part of your question, but if it is an issue, ask a new question.

Comment: Your code works, thank you.  
However, maybe, you can still help me with the mechanic. I do not quite get why it works...
In your first statement you take all tuples of the input graph, but then your recursive call,
I do not see how this can possibly work... 
Since you are always joining - as far as I am concerned - you would miss the results of all recursion except the last one...
This is why added the third UNION ALL into my original try.
Why is this not needed?

Comment: No need to worry, further. I have proven why it works 

Comment: @Niclas so if this solves your problem and you think this is the optimal solution, you can [mark the answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).